# AS3: Access function in external class located in external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, class, dynamic

I am trying to access a function in a loaded swf that has external class..
I would like to avoid having to put the function on my "Main" Doc class in the external swf
and instead access the function directly from the class

This is what ive tried so far and it's a no dice:

```
 private function startLoad(){
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("one.swf");
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
        loader.load(req);

    }
 private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void{
        var ClassDefinition:Class = e.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("com.view.Creative") as Class;
        var butn:MovieClip = new ClassDefinition(0,0);////0,0 is x and y cordinates I have in the "com.view.Creative" class

        this.addChild(butn);
        butn.setVar("one");////"setVar" is the function in my external swf with the class "com.view.Creative"
    }
```

This is the function in com.view.Creative.as

```
  public var storedVar:String

  public function setVar(str:String):void{
               this.storedVar = str;
               trace(storedVar)
    }
```

//Returns "ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property setVar not found on com.view.Creative and there is no default value."

This is the other approach I took with no success

```
  private function startLoad(){
        var appDomain:ApplicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain();
        var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, appDomain);
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 
        loader.load(new URLRequest("one.swf"), context);


    }

  private function completeHandler(event:Event):void { 
        var myGreet:Class = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition("com.view.Creative") as Class;                
        var app : MovieClip = new myGreet(0,0)
        addChild(app);
        app.setVar("one");////set var is the function in my external swf with the class "com.view.Creative" I am trying to access
        //event.target.content.setVar("one");///this works if I am placing my "setVar" function on my "Main" Doc Class which I am trying to avoid///

    }
```

This is the function in com.view.Creative.as

```
   public var storedVar:String

   public function setVar(str:String):void{
               this.storedVar = str;
               trace(storedVar)
    }
```

//Returns "ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property setVar not found on com.view.Creative and there is no default value.
    at com.util::ClickArea/completeHandler()"

There's gotta be a solution for this.....Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in second case try this :

```
 var myGreet:Class = event.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("com.view.Creative") as Class;
```

event.target is Your contentLoaderInfo .

If You loading swf into new ApplicationDomain , You cannot look for definition in currentDomain .

in first case , maybe You already have class Creative under this alias but with different params and when You load swf to currentDomain , class :"com.view.Creative" will not overwrite existing , but return class from main swf.

Comment: var myGreet:Class = event.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition("com.view.Creative") as Class;                                                                                                                                                                                                      That solved it!!!! Thanks much @turbosqel

Comment: no problem , You should read something about ApplicationDomain to understand how it works ;)